# Problemas con Imagen en JLabel

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un simulador y estoy intentando poner una imagen en un JLabel y despues ese JLabel agregarlo a un JFrame con una imagen de fondo, el frame con la imagen de fondo se encuentra en otra clase, el problema es que cuando ejecuto el programa no aparece la imagen en el JFrame este es el codigo donde agrego el JLabel

```
public static void CreaTaquillero(JLabel taquilleros, int x) {
          ventanasim.setLayout(null);
          Image img= new 
          ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Luis\\Desktop\\icon.png").getImage();
          ImageIcon img2=new ImageIcon(img.getScaledInstance(100, 84, 
          Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));

          taquilleros.setIcon(img2);
          taquilleros.setBounds(1100,10,30,30);
          taquilleros.setSize(taquilleros.getPreferredSize());
          ventanasim.add(taquilleros);
    }
```

Comment: creo que te falta que sea visible, setVisible()

Comment: @x-rw ¿ en donde te refieres falta setVisible()?

Answer (score -1):

Revisando tu código te sugiero, verificar que tu imagen en realidad se encuentre en la ruta especificada, revisa el nombre y la extensión el archivo sean correctos:

```
"C:\Users\Luis\Desktop\icon.png"
```

El código es correcto en cuanto a el escalado de la imagen.

Además de debugging, puedes validar también si la imagen no se encuentra muestre un mensaje en el `JLabel`:

```
public static void CreaTaquillero(JLabel taquilleros, int x) {
          ventanasim.setLayout(null);
          Image img= new 
          ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Luis\\Desktop\\icon.png").getImage();
          ImageIcon img2=new ImageIcon(img.getScaledInstance(100, 84, 
          Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));

        if (img2 != null) {
          taquilleros.setIcon(img2);
          taquilleros.setBounds(1100,10,30,30);
          taquilleros.setSize(taquilleros.getPreferredSize());    
        } else {
                taquilleros.setText("NO SE ENCUENTRA IMAGEN EN RUTA ESPECIFICADA!");
        }

          ventanasim.add(taquilleros);

    }
```

Comment: Ya lo cheque pero al parecer si encuentra la imagen, por que no aparece el mensaje de la ruta incorrecta  :( sigue sin aparecer

Comment: Entonces debe ser el contenedor donde se agrega el JLabel, veo que tienes ventanasim.setLayout(null); ?. Agrega tu código.

Comment: Estuve checando y ya pude agregar las imágenes, pero solo desde el constructor de la clase, el problema solo ocurre cuando la intento agregar desde un método

Comment: Ok entonces agrega como creas taquilleros que envias al método CreaTaquillero().

Comment: **CP 301 Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.